# The role of linear combination in definition of a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am an undergraduate who just finished taking my first course in Linear Algebra. I am wanting to get a deeper understanding of the subject out of interest and for its wide reaching applications (primarily to physics).

To do so, I have been working through Hoffman and Kunze's 2nd Edition of Linear Algebra. I am on the second chapter, which concerns vector spaces.

Kunze defines a vector space in the way I was taught this past semester: axiomatically. He then defines subspaces as such:

"Let **V** be a vector space and **F** be a field. A subspace of **V** is a subset **W** of V which is itself a vector space over **F** with the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication on V."

The first theorem presented after this definition states:

"A non-empty subset of **W** of **V** is a subspace of **V** iff for each pair of vectors **a**, **b** in **W** and each scalar c in **F** the vector c**a** + **b** is again in **W**."

Now, the definition of a subspace that I am familiar with is something like "a subspace of a vector space V is a subset of the vectors in V closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. This translates into closure under linear combination."

I am quite confused as to why Kunze uses "...c**a** + **b** is again in **W**" instead of closure under linear combination which would look like ""...c**a** + d**b** is again in **W**."

My thought is that "...c**a** + **b** is again in **W**" actually implies that "...c**a** + d**b** is again in **W**". Thus, it is unnecessary to say closure under linear combination. I have thought through a sketch of this proof which goes something like:

Let W be a non-empty subset of vectors in vector space V on field F such that for vectors **a**, **b** and for an arbitrary scalar c in the field F c**a** + **b** is contained in W. I.e. let W be a subspace as defined by Kunze. Then, any scalar multiple of **a** is itself a vector in W because we can set **b** to be the **0** vector which necessarily must be in a subspace. If we then now set **b** to be the said scalar multiples of **a** that we just found out are elements of W, we can now input our original arbitrary vectors **b** in c**a** and produce linear combinations of vectors **a**, **b** as we set out to do.

However, one of the chapter's emphasis is that it's useful to consider a set of objects and linear combinations of said objects. So, why not emphasize it here?

Further adding to my confusion is Kunze's theorem 3:

"The subspace spanned by a non-empty subset S of a vector space V is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in S."

Here, Kunze actually refers to linear combinations of vectors in S. Now, if my hypothesis about "...c**a** + **b** is again in **W**" implying that "...c**a** + d**b** is again in **W**" is correct, why wouldn't Kunze just say "...is the set of all combinations of vectors in S of the form c**a** + **b**"?

This leads me to believe I am misunderstanding something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Explicit edit: I thought it might be helpful to provide Kunze's proof for the above stated theorem 1:

[image: Kunze's theorem 1]

Below is Kunze's definition of a subspace spanned by a subset, theorem 3, and theorem 3's proof.

[image: Spanned Subspace Definition + Theorem 3]

Comment: How does Kunze defines subspace spanned by a subset?

Comment: Let me post pictures of the text. One moment.

Comment: I have posted a picture of Kunze's definition of subspace spanned by a subset as well as theorem 3 and its proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to show that $\textbf a, b \in W \Rightarrow c\textbf a + \textbf b \in W$ implies $\textbf 0 \in W$, but it's simple (and essentially proved in the proof of theorem 1).

For non-empty $W \subseteq V$, the following are equivalent:

1. $W$ is vector space itself (with the same operations)
2. $W$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication
3. $W$ is closed under taking linear combinations
4. if $\textbf a, \textbf b \in W$ and $c \in F$ then $c \textbf a + \textbf b \in W$
5. if $\textbf a, \textbf b \in W$ and $c,d \in F$ then $c \textbf a + d \textbf b \in W$

The 4th variant is usually shortest to write, while the 2nd is simplest to check.

For the theorem 3, it's important to consider all linear combinations, not just of form $c\textbf a + \textbf b$, because when you talk about building a closure (not of checking if something is closed) you may need to use this operations more than once. And set $\{c\textbf a + \textbf b | \textbf a, b \in S, c \in F\}$ in general isn't a subspace spanned by $S$.

For example, if $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $S = \{(0, 1), (1, 0)\}$, then subspace spanned by $S$ is entire $V$, but vector $(2, 2)$ isn't of form $c\textbf a + \textbf b$.

Comment: Just to check my understanding of your answer: 

Your first sentence refers to the proof that variants (the ones you stated) 4 and 5 are equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, is Kunze's use of variant 4 just a matter of conciseness? Thinking about variant 2 makes the most sense to me, and I am wondering if thinking about subspaces in this way will hamper my ability to understand other concepts in linear algebra or follow proofs in Kunze. I feel it makes most sense because it seems the simplest since if a, b are vectors in V and c, d are scalars in F, closure under s. multiplication => ca is in V and db is in V; and if closure under v. addition the previous implication => ca + db is in V.

Comment: The first line of Kunze's proof of theorem 3 seems to invoke the definition of a subspace. In particular, that a subspace W spanned by S which is a subset of V is itself a vector space under the operations of V. This invocation leads Kunze to state that all linear combinations of vectors in S are "clearly" in W. If all that is being invoked is the fact that W is a subspace, then mustn't Kunze solely be working with the fact that vectors of the form ca + b are also in W to come to the conclusion that linear combinations ca + db are also in W?

Comment: But, I must be wrong since your counter example makes sense.

Comment: Yes, the first line is about your "we can set b to be the 0 vector". For use variant 4 as definition - yes, I think just because it's the most compact.

Comment: Any subspace is closed wrt linear combinations, so in particular any subspace that contains $S$ contains any linear combination of elements of $S$, and so subspace spanned by $S$ contains it too. Note that first theorem takes arbitrary $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from **supspace**, not just from subset that spans it.